# Simple Token based authentication in FastAPI that does not require users?

Tags: fastapi

I have created a very simple API with FastAPI to access text files on the filesystem.
It runs in a docker container that has only access to a volume, not the host filesystem and is accessible via a private network in docker from other containers.
The whole app is simple, just 112 lines, and should just store some test files for other containers to access.

I would like to add a simple Token bases authentication to the API. I have found many examples, but they assume that we have users accessing the API. Hence they require to setup a user DB etc.
In my case there is only a machine to machine communication with other apps in docker containers.

Is there any way to have a simple Token based authentication added without the overhead of users? Maybe set a single Token for all access that can be read form the environment variable at the start of the container.

Comment: Could something like `JWT` work for you? https://jwt.io/

Comment: I looked at some examples with JWT, but they all seem to require a proper user management and some sort of DB(SQLight) to store the information. I was hoping to get around the whole user management.

Comment: You can provide an API key to the user. Though, this will require some sort of authentication, otherwise you can provide to anyone the API key, or just remove the security verification. With JWT, you can create your own token and sign it, but again, if you can give it to anyone, what's the point?

Comment: Well, as I explained. This is for a machine to machine communication, not for users. So the other machine will get the token, not "everyone". It the purpose is to prevent that "everyone" gets access to the API.

Comment: Ok, then the token based authentication can be used. Maybe a JWT token in which you place information about the machine (e.g. IP if static) and verify it at every request. Otherwise, just provide the token alone

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. But all examples with JWT Token refer to users or barrier token. Limiting by IP might not be an option as the app will be deployed as containers in the cloud.

Comment: The tutorial on `fastapi` is a great example. You then need to adapt it in order to achieve what you need, as for every other tutorial.... https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/?h=jwt Encrypt some other information in the token if you don't want the IP. Mine was just a suggestion